# Gradle console - get more log output

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android studio. In the gradle console getting the below error message

> Compilation error. See log for more details
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

But where to run **--info option** to see the more log ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Steps to get this feature is as follows:-

1. Goto settings options of android studio.
2. In the list of items You will see Build, Execution, deployment option.
3. If you click on this you will see Compiler option there you can add command-line options ex:- stacktrace --debug.

Answer (score 39):

This question was written a couple of years ago but the answer is still relevant with the latest upgrade to Android Studio 3.1.3.  I noticed that I couldn't see the gradle logs, and after some hunting and pecking I found that you can show and hide the gradle logs with the little button shown in the attached screenshot. It's not very well advertised, so if you're missing gradle logs then cycle that button.
[image: Toggle Gradle Log View]

Comment: You may have to click the gear icon in the "Build / Sync" pane's title bar first and check/tick "Show Toolbar".

Comment: I no longer have this button.  Android Studio 3.3.

Answer (score 31):

try below way, add one of these `--info, --stacktrace, --debug` in command line option

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Console variant for [log level](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html): debug, info, warn, quiet, [default]

```
//Unix
./gradlew <task> -d

//e.g
./gradlew publishToMavenLocal -d
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides "where to run", which has already been answered in this question:

#### [LOGGING](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_logging)

The following are the [Gradle logging options](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#setting_log_level) available:

> You can customize the verbosity of Gradle logging with the following
> options, ordered from least verbose to most verbose. Learn more in the
> logging documentation.
>
> -Dorg.gradle.logging.level=(quiet,warn,lifecycle,info,debug) Set logging level via Gradle properties.
>
> -q, --quiet Log errors only.
>
> -w, --warn Set log level to warn.
>
> -i, --info Set log level to info.
>
> -d, --debug Log in debug mode (includes normal stacktrace).
>
> Lifecycle is the default log level.

#### [DEBUG](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_debugging)

and the following are the [debug options](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_debugging):

> -?, -h, --help Shows a help message with all available CLI options.
>
> -v, --version Prints Gradle, Groovy, Ant, JVM, and operating system version information.
>
> -S, --full-stacktrace Print out the full (very verbose) stacktrace for any exceptions. See also logging options.
>
> -s, --stacktrace Print out the stacktrace also for user exceptions (e.g. compile error). See also logging options.
>
> --scan Create a build scan with fine-grained information about all aspects of your Gradle build.
>
> -Dorg.gradle.debug=true Debug Gradle client (non-Daemon) process. Gradle will wait for you to attach a debugger at localhost:5005 by
> default.
>
> -Dorg.gradle.debug.port=(port number) Specifies the port number to listen on when debug is enabled. Default is 5005.
>
> -Dorg.gradle.debug.server=(true,false) If set to true and debugging is enabled, Gradle will run the build with the socket-attach mode of the
> debugger. Otherwise, the socket-listen mode is used. Default is true.
>
> -Dorg.gradle.debug.suspend=(true,false) When set to true and debugging is enabled, the JVM running Gradle will suspend until a debugger is
> attached. Default is true.
>
> -Dorg.gradle.daemon.debug=true Debug Gradle Daemon process.

Answer (score 1):

This started changing for me on the newer version of **Android Studio**. I hadn't changed anything, but, for me at least, it was **not** a problem of the logging not coming in... it was a problem with which of the build outputs Android Studio was focusing on.

So if I made a basic compilation problem in my file and tried to install it on  a device, I would get this:

[image]

You see the error to the right (and I wasted a lot of time trying to set up the right preferences to get it to show the log details), but that wasn't the problem.

If you look to the left, it is preselecting/highlighting one of the errors. If I select the one above it (the :compileDebugKotlinAndroid one), then I get the right error. Heck, if I select the top level one (Build support: failed), I can scroll up and get the right problem too.

For some reason, every time I try to install my app and there is a compilation problem, it just defaults to that jetbrain's CompilationErrorException one.

Should I have looked at that window on the left first before I immediately tried to figure out why the log details weren't coming in?

Yes... yes, I should have, but hopefully my wasted time will save you some time. :D